# Как скрыть курсор или заменить его на свой глобально

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, курсор

Как это можно выполнить? Где это выполнить (html css js), и, если можно, напишите код для сего действия, чтобы я смог вставить код в проект, и курсор пропал.

Comment: html { cursor:  url ("путь к курсору") }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так можно прямо в `css` установить `svg` курсор, обратите внимание что символы `<` и `>` экранированы как `%3C` и `%3E`, остальное в целом то же

```
cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32' height='32' viewBox='-50 -50 100 100'%3E %3Ccircle r='40' stroke-width='4' fill='white' stroke='red' %3C/svg%3E"), auto;
```

В сниппете так же показано как поставить в качестве курсора картинку или совсем убрать его

```css
.svg-cursor {
  background-color: snow;
  cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32' height='32' viewBox='-50 -50 100 100'%3E %3Ccircle r='40' stroke-width='4' fill='white' stroke='red' /%3E %3Ccircle r='30' stroke-width='4' fill='white' stroke='green' /%3E %3Ccircle r='20' stroke-width='4' fill='white' stroke='blue' /%3E  %3C/svg%3E") 16 16, pointer;
}

.no-cursor {
  cursor: none;
  background-color: wheat;
}

.img-cursor {
  cursor: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q67w.gif), auto;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
  width:33.33vw;
  height:100vh;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="svg-cursor">svg cursor</section>
<section class="img-cursor">img cursor</section>
<section class="no-cursor">no cursor</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

В CSS файле (или на html в странице в теге )пропишите "yourdivstyle {cursor:none};", где **yourdivstyle** - блочный оператор кода в html (DIV)

Контент, который необходимо скрыть, поместите в тег :

```
<div class="yourdivstyle">
Контент, где не нужен курсор
</div>
```